# Pandas, position of iloc in df

Tags: python, pandas

The following code produces the same result.  Can I use both interchangeably?  Will I run into problems later?

Thank you

```
Method1: df.iloc[0]['A']

Method2: df['A'].iloc[0]
```

Comment: There the same, it's just a matter of taste and readability

Comment: Note that these will *not* always be equivalent when setting the value with these constructs. But for getting the value, this is safe.

Comment: @joris I get no warning on setting on both, I would've expected the first version to moan but it didn't

Comment: For mixed dtype frames you'll get a warning on the first, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": ['a', 'b']})`

Comment: Indeed, with mixed types and with pandas 0.17.1, I get a warning for both, but the second does work and the first not (as expected)

Comment: @TomAugspurger why does the presence of mixed dtypes result in the warning but homogenous ones don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result in both case is the same as suggested. But it might be useful, to make the process as clear as possible. In your case you at first generate a Series object and you then pick one element of it.

- `df.iloc[0]['A']   #1st. generate Series: row with index 0., 2nd. pick element 'A'`
- `df['A'].iloc[0]   #1st. generate Series: col with name 'A'., 2nd. pick element 0`

Even though you have asked for iloc, if you want just to select the value, I would go for df.loc[0, 'A']. This is somehow consistent with matrix notation. Pick row=0 and col='A' from matrix df.